# Mootools Selector issue

Tags: javascript, mootools

Right now I have a dynamic string that assigns it's values to a particular div class.
Output looks like this

```
  <div class="12923"></div>
```

I want to find that 'randNumber' div, then check if it has another class 'x'

Currently what I have now doesn't work:

```
  var randNumber = 12923

  var lookingForYou = $$('.'+randNumber);
  if (lookingForYou.hasClass('XCLASS')){alert('XCLASS FOUND!');}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ returns an array of all matching elems. Not sure if you can do a hasclass on an array. Might have to do a .each() then do it. Try $('body').getElement('.'+randNumber).hasClass('XCLASS') this way you grab 1 elem if you don't want to mess with the array.

Answer (score 2):

$$ returns an Elements instance, Elements is an array-like Class
anyway since you are basically filtering, you can tell Slick that you need an element with both class:

```
 var randNumber = 12923;
 if($$('.' + randNumber +'.XCLASS').length>0){
     alert('XCLASS FOUND');
 }else{
     //dostuff
 }
```

or you could just use one of the Elements methods, I think .some will be your best choice here:

```
    var randNumber = 12923

    var lookingForYou = $$('.' + randNumber);

    alert(lookingForYou.some(function(el){
        return el.hasClass('XCLASS');
    }))
```

EDIT:

adding some links:

[A better way to use Elements on MooTools blog](http://mootools.net/blog/2010/03/19/a-better-way-to-use-elements/)

in my second example I used the some method, which, by looking at the source is not overloaded, but is just the one in Array.prototype.some:

[Element.js source reference](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Element/Element.js#L200-202)

[Array.some on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
if (lookingForYou.hasClass('XCLASS')){alert('XCLASS FOUND!');}
```

`$$()` returns an array, and `hasClass()` performs the check on each element of the array, returning an array of booleans. Unfortunately, when you check `if (...)`, then the return array, *even if all of the values are `false`*, is evaluated as `true` because it's non-empty.